# Accessing Drawer label inside component react-native navigation 6

Tags: react-native, label, navigation-drawer

How can I access the label of the drawer inside the page where I am actually implementing the component? example:

DrawerNavigator.js

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import Home from '../screens/Home'
import Contact from '../screens/Contact'

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const DrawerNavigation= (props) => {

  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      <Drawer.Screen 
        key='home'
        name= "home page"
        component={Home}
      />

      <Drawer.Screen 
        key='contact' 
        name="contact us"
        component={Contact}    
      />    
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default DrawerNavigation;
```

Now I want to access the drawer label in my Home.js file which is the following:

```
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native"

const Home = (props) =>{
   
    return (<View>
        <Text>Hello world</Text>
    </View>)
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as `initialParams` to you navigation screen.
Kindly follow [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#initial-params) for details/example

Comment: Passing data between screens is not my issue. My problem is that I have one screen where I can change the language (French, English) and the navigation drawer labels should reflect the language. So I want to be able to change the labels of the navigation drawer from that screen.